# German word to array

Tags: php, arrays

I would like convert a string to an array by using str_split(). But I have german words in this string, for example Überraschung. So in string is `"&Uuml;berraschung"`. I dont want to change the string using html_entity_decode().

Is it possible create array looking like this?

```
array([0] => "&Uuml;",
    [1] => "b", 
    [2] => "e", 
    [3] => "r", 
    [4] => "r", 
    [5] => "a", 
    [6] => "s", 
    [7] => "c", 
    [8] => "h", 
    [9] => "u", 
    [10] => "n", 
    [11] => "g");
```

Comment: I believe you can achieve that with the in-built function [mb_str_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-str-split.php#refsect1-function.mb-str-split-description)

Comment: Do you absolutely want to retain the HTML entity form of `&Uuml;` or is it ok for you to place `Ü` in the array?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a custom function for you according to your scenerio. I hope it will help you.

```
<?php
function str_split_unicode($str, $l = 0) {
    if ($l > 0) {
        $ret = array();
        $len = mb_strlen($str, "UTF-8");
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i += $l) {
            $ret[] = mb_substr($str, $i, $l, "UTF-8");
        }
        return $ret;
    }
    return preg_split("//u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
print_r(str_split_unicode("Überraschung"));
?>
```

**Output (Array):**

```
Array ( [0] => Ü [1] => b [2] => e [3] => r [4] => r [5] => a [6] => s [7] => c [8] => h [9] => u [10] => n [11] => g )
```

Comment: OP doesn't seem to be dealing with unicode, but rather an HTML entity. Have you tried your function on the literal value from the question (`"&Uuml;berraschung"`)?

Comment: Actually the user was splitting the string after applying html_entity_decode. Thats incorrect. he should apply the function after splitting the values.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion of what the user was doing since no code was posted?

Comment: The way you proposed the solution the same versa i proposed mine. So dont worry.

Comment: There is a major difference between my answer and yours - mine works with what was actually posted in the question - the string `&Uuml;berraschung`. All I have asked you is have you tested your function with this string?

Comment: Don't worry Man. Let the user whome the answer will be approve.